# Dhtml Transitions

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

Is it possible to move the slide from left to right, when the user click the button. I am using progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Slide(slideStyle='PUSH', bands=1). It moves from right to left as way I need to move from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

DXImageTransform in an IE-only function.

Most commonly this can be accomplished using any popular JavaScript library, such as jQuery or Prototype/Scriptaculous.

Using [Prototype/Scriptaculous](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-move) you could do this:

```
new Effect.Move('divName',{mode:'relative',x:-500,y:0})
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to like this, but since transitions are an IE specific feature I would *strongly* recommend avoiding them entirely and finding another way to create the effect you want.

I'd start by looking at [Mootools animations](http://demos.mootools.net/) and consider how these can interact with AJAX techniques.